# iOS: Disable UITableView selection after tap and hold a cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, selection

I have a `UITableView` with custom `UITableViewCell`s displayed inside a modal view controller. When the cell is selected, I am pushing a new `UIViewController` onto the navigation stack. All standard but I have found a strange bug with this:

Say I have 10 cells displayed in the table view. If I tap and hold on one cell and use another finger to randomly tap on other cells, after I release my fingers, there are multiple `UIViewControllers` pushed on top of each other. I guess it makes sense, as I am calling `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` multiple times. However, I have no idea how to fix it ?

I am getting the error: "`nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar`" 
and : "`Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.`"

I am setting `exclusivieTouch` to `YES` on the cells as well as `delaysContentTouches` to `NO` on the tableView.

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable multiple selection of the table view(by setting `tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = NO;`, this is by default. So maybe you just need to remove your setting it to YES code). It doesn't make sense to allow user's multiple selection if it's to present a view controller. Because only one can be presented.

Comment: This does not help unfortunately. If I tap and hold a cell and keep tapping other cells, then multiple view controller will be pushed. I dont know why it does it. I have also found the same problem in other table views that I am using, so it shouldn't be a simple bug I have missed.

Comment: You ever find the solution to this?